# Interfacing with Canon printer/scanner

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner

I've just installed 16.04 on an old spare Toshiba Satellite laptop.  Looking for some initial help with peripherals - specifically networked Canon MG6320 printer/scanner.   Was able to easily identify the printer print a test page but have two open issues

1) the test page printed some sample color wheels, but the color definition is not what I think it should be.  (Can't see any difference between red and magenta, yellow is more like a light olive) This leads me to believe it's just a generic driver.  Reinforced by the fact that when went to Canon's download site, it detected I was running Linux and informed me there were no drivers available.

2) The printer's network scan function depends on software installed on the computer.  Of course, the installation CD from Canon only deals with Windows and Mac.

Any suggestions on this in particular, or the more general question of how to deal with peripherals when the manufacturers only provide software for Windows and Mac?

Comment: Ok, I thought I had posted the above yesterday, but when I came back to check for reponses, couldn't find it.  Then when I clicked on 'ask a question, the page loaded up with my question, ready to post!   So . . .  in the mean time, I was able to locate the drivers on another (non-USA) Canon site, got them installed and can now print and scan, though not as cleanly as with the untility provided for a Windows system.   But still leaves the general question ... Is there a general approach to supporting peripherals when the manufacturers only provide support for Windows and Mac?